# Error in installing apps bigcommerce

Tags: python, python-2.7, bigcommerce

I am building an application in bigcommerce using python API, I am following all the instructions given in the [site.](https://github.com/bigcommerce/hello-world-app-python-flask)

Everything is fine up to setting up the project, but while installing application present in my drafts in my store it is just showing installing and is doing nothing so can you help me.